# Simply diagnosis or diagnosed or diagnosing and dispensing low vision aids is not sufficient to manage low vision patients

Tags: grammar

*emphasized text*
which word should I use in this? is it diagnosis or diagnosed or diagnosing in the above sentence and the reasons

Help me

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the context please? Are you writing something? By “low vision aids” do you simply mean glasses (spectacles) and contact lens, or other things too?

Answer (score -1):

When you use the word "`and`", both ***before*** `and` ***after*** parts need to go along in every aspect e.g. word type, tense, sense of meaning.

In this case the word "dispensing" ***is*** a gerund `and` ***locates*** after the word "`and`", so the word that you put before "`and`" as well need to be gerund, **diagnosing**.

Additionally, if you think of another aspect by the sense of meaning, it could be **diagnosed**, which would make the meaning of the sentence goes as *the aids was being **diagnosed** before **dispensing***.

Comment: I think you are trying to communicate a correct answer, but your sentences are not well constructed and your word choice is unusual. For example, I think I know what you are driving at, but “parts need to go along” is a strange way to say it.